# what is a real pointer in valgrind when detecting 'memory leak'?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks, valgrind

As document says：

```
(5)  RRR -?-> BBB  (y)DR, (n)DL

Pointer chain legend:
- RRR: a root set node or DR block
- AAA, BBB: heap blocks
- --->: a start-pointer
- -?->: an interior-pointer

Leak Case legend:
- DR: Directly reachable
- IR: Indirectly reachable
- DL: Directly lost
- IL: Indirectly lost
- (y)XY: it's XY if the interior-pointer is a real pointer
- (n)XY: it's XY if the interior-pointer is not a real pointer
- (_)XY: it's XY in either case
```

> [Valgrind Documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.leaks)

#### Case1:

```
void *RRR;
int main()
{
    RRR = malloc(4);
    RRR = (char*)RRR + 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Output：

```
==3390== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3390==      possibly lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
```

#### Case2:

```
void *RRR;
int main()
{
    RRR = malloc(4);
    *(int*)RRR = 4;
    RRR = (char*)RRR + 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
==3414== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3414==      possibly lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
```

Two cases output same result. **'real pointer'** mean what?  And '_' stand for what?

`(y)XY: it's XY if the interior-pointer is a real pointer`. How to change `XY` to be a real pointer?

Comment: Your 2 cases are the exact same. The only difference is that you assign a value to the memory that RRR points to in the second case. Valgrind doesn't care what value you assign to the memory. The leak in both cases is the exact same.

Comment: Once you assign a new value to pointer `RRR` you lose the only pointer to the start of your malloc'd block.  From valgrind's perspective, this block is therefore lost.  It is only "possibly" lost, however, because you still have a pointer *into* the block, from which you could conceivably recover the original pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is a little bit old question, but maybe it will be helpful for someone in future.

Your question is related with "real pointer" in following statements of documentation:

```
- (y)XY: it's XY if the interior-pointer is a real pointer
- (n)XY: it's XY if the interior-pointer is not a real pointer
```

This statements are related with interior-pointers. Documentation says that interior-pointer may be:

> It might be a random junk value in memory, entirely unrelated, just a coincidence.

in such case the interior-pointer is not considered a real-pointer, so in such case

```
(5)  RRR -?-> BBB  (y)DR, (n)DL
```

will be considered directly lost memory ((n)DL). If the interior-pointer is a pointer variable, but e.g. advanced to point into middle of allocated memory block, as you did in Case 2, then it is considered directly reachable ((y)DR).

Pay attention that this is my understanding of the documentation and I'm